# How can I write to a text file using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, export

I am programming in VBA and I have a string variable which contains my data. I would like to write these data to a .txt file and leave this txt file open once the script has ended running.

How can I program that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something ? because i googled your question and I have found the answer... like that http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/write-data-to-text-file.html (just donc close it at the end)

Comment: It is trivially easy to locate answers to your question. Stack Overflow should be where you go when you get stuck, not where you begin.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
Sub GergoBarta()
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\TestFile.txt" For Output As #1
    MyText = "Hello World"
    Print #1, MyText
End Sub
```